# RecyclerView Blank space between items when multiple view types are used

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**The screen i am trying to design:**

[image]

The items are added in Gridlayout. There are two types of views. RED, this needs 1 span. and Blue - needs 2 span.

Following code is used to fill the RecyclerView with right span for two different view types:

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
    layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
            return when (adapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                ViewType.BLUE  -> 2
                else -> 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem:
The Blue views are added dynamically in different position. If they aren't added in right position. My UI would look like this:

[image]

There will be empty space if BLUE view doesn't have enough space.

**Possible Solution**
I tried to solve the issue while creating AdapterListsItems. Logically, the Blue view must be inserted only in Even index. I added a check and it worked as expected.
But, this RecyclerView has few more views type. and tracking the right position for the Blue View type difficult.

Is there any way to handle this scenario ?